# What the difference between k050 and k124

Tags: rear-wheel

I have an old kids bike. It has been in our family for at least 30+ years.
However it was left in the rain by the our resisdent bike killer.  Its a bloody mess so unless am told otherwise i think its best to buy a new rear wheel

But am unsure the difference between the two sizes. 
http://www.tredz.co.uk/.Kenda-Kids-12-inch-Tyres_40597.htm

Comment: Those are not wheel size descriptions that I recognise. Where did you get the terms? Normally wheel size is most easily found by reading off the tyre  size. [See Sheldon Brown's page](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) for some information on what to look for.

Comment: I am confused how changing the tire will correct the damage from leaving a bike out in the rain.  In my fairly considerable experience with such bikes, the tires will survive quite well, but other components -- chains, cables, bearings -- will suffer due to severe rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not sizes, they are both the same size. The K050 and K124 are Kenda's designation for tread pattern.

K124:
[image]

K050:
[image]